# Spring logging priority

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2, spring-logback

The Spring logging documentation is available [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging) and describes the different logging possibilities. However, something I have not been able to find is the priority of the different configurations. More concretely, in `application.properties` I enabled logging for showing basic authentication failures by doing:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www=DEBUG
```

This works fines and enabled the logs I expect to see. Then I checked if I could override the configuration above via `log4j2.xml` by including:

```
<Logger name="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
    <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE"/>
</Logger>
```

The change in `log4j2.xml` did not cause any effect. So my impression is that the logging configuration included in `applications.properties` takes priority over `log4j2.xml`  (or it is read after). The only note I can see in the documentation that may be related is:

> Since logging is initialized before the ApplicationContext is created,
> it is not possible to control logging from @PropertySources in Spring
> @Configuration files. The only way to change the logging system or
> disable it entirely is through System properties.

So my assumption is that the following will happen:

1. Logging is configured according to `log4j2.xml`.
2. Spring loads the Application context and then the logging configuration in `application.properties` is taken and "wins".

So my question is, if someone knows how this is supposed to work without guessing (a link will be appreciated). **NOTE:** I am interested because I want to be sure that no `log4j2.xml` will disable the spring-security logging.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

application.properties/application.yaml take precedence over log4j2.xml - [search for precedence here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html)

Environment variables take precedence over application.properties/application.yaml

A fuller precedence list is [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config)

Comment: Great! I was looking in the wrong place. Thanks John!